# How to center a button right in the middle of two divs, but a z-index order higher?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm having issues implementing the following design:

[image]

My specific problem is the blue button in the center, and subsequently the arrow in the middle of it.

I currently have two elements:

```
<div id="hero">
<!-- this is where the black background is -->
</div>

<div id="content">
<!-- This is the white background -->
</div>
```

Now somehow, I have to put that blue button right in the middle of the hero and the rest of the content, and on top of that, there has to be an arrow in the middle of that button and the button.

I don't know where to start doing this. I'm assuming the button needs to have a `z-index` higher than the hero and the content, and the arrow has to have a `z-index` higher than the blue button.

But in what part of the HTML document do I write the tags in? For example:

```
<div id="hero">
<!-- This is the black background -->
</div>
<button type="button" class="cta">Button Tex bla bla</button>
<button type="button" class="arrow"><img src="..."></button>

<div id="content">
<!-- This is the white background -->
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap for the grid.

Comment: Typically you want to write your HTML in the order it would appear naturally if you were reading a website like a document. You can always take elements out of the natural flow (if necessary) using properties like `float` or `position`.

Answer (score 2):

With the combination of `position` and `margin` you can position the elements the way you want:

```css
#container{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#hero{
    height: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#hero span{
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#content{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 80px;
}

#content span{
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.cta{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.arrow{
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="hero">
        <span>hero headline so cool buy now</span>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" class="cta">Button Tex bla bla</button>
    <button type="button" class="arrow">V</button>

    <div id="content">
        <span>give me more money</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use style tag relative position and offset the top by half of the buttons length. And yes use the z-index to place it on top.

```
    <div id="hero">
<!-- This is the black background -->
</div>
<button type="button" class="cta" style="position:relative; top: -20px;">Button Tex bla bla</button>
<button type="button" class="arrow" style="position:relative; top: -20px;"><img src="..."></button>

<div id="content">
<!-- This is the white background -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can do

```css
.cta{
  position:relative;
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
<!-- This is the black background -->
</div>
<button type="button" class="cta">
  Button Tex bla bla
  <a href="#" class="arrow">
    <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/super-mono-sticker-icons-by-double-j-design/png/64/arrow-down.png">
  </a> 
</button>  
<div id="content">
<!-- This is the white background -->
</div>
```

use **position:relative;** on parent element and **position:absolute;** on child element

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try :) - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3f56qb6/1/)

I am basically wrapping the buttons in an absolute div `button-wrapper` ( absolute to the Hero ) then I just center its content using `text-align:center`

```
  <div id="hero">
     <h1>My Title</h1>

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="blue cta">Button Tex bla bla</button>
        <button type="button" class="arrow"><span>&#8595;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- This is the white background -->
</div>



#hero {
background:#000;
height: 300px;
text-align:center;
}
h1 {
    color:white;
    padding: 50px;
}
button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:500px;
    z-index:10;
}
.blue {
    background: #0185CB;
    color:#fff;
}
.cta {
    border: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
}
.arrow {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.arrow > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the two buttons doing the same thing? If yes, you should use only one button.

You can try this since you are using bootstrap:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    //container fluid will always have full width of its parent
    <div class="container-fluid" id="my-button-wrapper">
        //you create a row in order to manage the div inside
        <div class="row">
            //create a column as wide as you want and push it to center it
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
                //then you add the button
                <button type="button" class="my-button-class">Button text</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-button-wrapper {
    margin-top: -20px;
}


//give the position relative in order to position the arrow at its center
.my-button-class {
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}



//this will add an element after the button content
.my-button-class:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-image: url('your-image-url');
    content: "";
}
```

Of course width and height of my element are just for example, you should use your own sizes or bootstrap's ones.